# Counter and for loops

Tags: python, count, iteritems

I am writing a piece of code that iterates through each record and prints a statistic called intervals.

```
for record in records:

    from collections import Counter
    count = Counter(intervals)

    for interval, frequency in count.iteritems():
        print interval
        print frequency
```

The output looks like this:

```
Record 1
199
7
200
30

Record 2
199
6
200
30
```

In this example, in Record 1, there are 7 instances of the interval length 199 and 30 instances of the interval length 200. In Record 2, there are 6 instances of the interval length 199 and 31 instances of the interval length 200.
I would like to see the overall stat summary of both records like this but cannot figure out how to get these results:

```
All Records

199
13

200
61
```

Where in both records, there are 13 instances total of interval length 199 (7+6) and 61 instances total of interval length 200 (30+31). I am having trouble getting the overall statistic summary of my records as shown above.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question by editing your post?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what exactly is your question? Also, please fix your indentation.

Comment: What do you want to know exactly ? Explain Clearly ...

Comment: Please indent your code properly. You can just add a variable that you add 1 to on every iteration. I would amend your code with a fuller explaination but I'm uncertain which peices of code belong in which for loop {ahhh the beauty of braces}

Comment: What's stored in `intervals` and in what format?

Comment: I think you want a `total = Counter()` outside the loop, then each time you do `count = Counter(intervals)` do a `total.update(count)`... then print `total` outside your loop? That'll give you cumulative totals along the way and a total total at the end... (but I'm not entirely sure...)

Comment: intervals  = [199,200,200,199,199, ......] It's an array of numbers.

Comment: @nikki_c or maybe `counts = Counter(); for record in records: counts.update(record)`... then do whatever you want with `counts`?

Comment: @JonClements with `Counter` objects, you could just do `total += count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need variable outside `for loop` that store the frequency counting
Following example may help you.

```
from collections import Counter


records = [[199,200,200], [200,199,200]]
freq_dist = Counter()                        # Variable store frequency distribution

for record in records:
    counts = Counter(record)
    freq_dist.update(counts)

for freq, value in freq_dist.items():
   print(freq, value)
```

Output:

```
200 4
199 2
```

Reference [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: Why are you using a `defaultdict(int)` instead of just a `Counter`, when you are already using `Counter` objects inside the loop?

Comment: Okay. I got it. I am not aware of that `Counter` support `update`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for suggestions. Updated answer.